# how to drop all civicrm tables using drush?

Tags: mysql, drush, cli

Civi is using it's own (not shared with Drupal) database.  During a script to rebuild a dev/test site from production data I want to drop all the tables in the civi dev db.  How do I do that?

After painstakingly trying `civitables=$(drush civicrm-sql-query "show tables" | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/,$//') && drush civicrm-sql-query "drop table $civitables"` I realized I could more simply do `drush civicrm-sql-query "drop table like 'civi%'"` but both of these are giving me "Query failed" error.  Why would these queries fail or what could I inspect to see why the failed?  How can all the tables be dropped using `drush`?

*edits...

The `drop table like...` is apparently invalid sql sytax.  Doh.

And the `civitables=$(drush civicrm-sql-query "show tables" | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/,$//') && drush civicrm-sql-query "drop table $civitables"` appears to fail due to `Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails` which apparently needs `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;` in order to work but when I do that the query passes (doesn't produce error) but fails to delete any tables.

Comment: Drupal has `drush sql-drop` and that's what I want for civicrm!

Answer (score 1):

There's a file in the [civicrm root]/sql folder called civicrm_drop.mysql. You should be able to use that as `source sql/civicrm_drop.mysql`. It doesn't drop views or the canary table, but you can do that separately.

Comment: so like `drush civicrm-sql-query --file=sites/all/modules/civicrm/sql/civicrm_drop.mysql` I presume is what you mean?

Comment: I've never used drush in that way but yes if `--file` means use the file as a sql script then yes. Alternatively `source` is a sql command so `drush civicrm-sql-query "source sql/civicrm_drop.mysql"` should work.

Comment: do you mean `drush civicrm-sql-query "source sites/all/modules/sql/civicrm_drop.mysql"`?

Comment: Right, you'd probably have to give the path from drupal root.

Comment: Any idea why civi's `civicrm_drop.mysql` doesn't drop tables that are "views"?

Comment: Probably just nobody's gone and implemented it.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen anything as clean as `drush sql-drop` (for drupal) yet, but the following works and is more thorough than the `civicrm/sql/civicrm_drop.mysql` file:

```
#!/bin/bash
# include this in devize.sh or whatever script is being used to rebuild your dev/test site

echo "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;" > drop-tables.sql
drush civicrm-sql-query "show tables" | sed -E 's/(.*)/DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `\1`;/g' >> drop-tables.sql
echo "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;" >> drop-tables.sql
drush civicrm-sql-query "source drop-tables.sql"
sed -i 's/TABLE/VIEW/g' drop-tables.sql
drush civicrm-sql-query "source drop-tables.sql"
rm drop-tables.sql

# then you'd go and do something like:
# drush cvsqlc < production_db.sql
# but that's not exactly relevant to this question
```

Comment: OMG -- if running on a *BSD server the `sed` commands are different :/
The second `sed` needs `''` added as an additional argument so it'd be
`sed -i '' 's/TABLE/VIEW/g'`.